Unable to pass flags to artisan test command
I have started learning laravel for one of my projects and almost everything works in the test commands except passing the arguments line --drop-databases.
./artisan test --drop-databases

Error message:
PHPUnit 11.1.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Unknown option "--drop-databases"

Laravel and PHP details
Application Name - Laravel  
Laravel Version - 11.7.0  
PHP Version - 8.3.3  
Composer Version - 2.7.1  


Have you update the signature of command and included the param you want to pass?

What does ./artisan execute? You should be running php artisan test --drop-databases, can you make 100% sure that is being executed?

Nope, when I run ./artisan it works (showing all the available commands). Infact when I run ./artisan test --help it works and shows the artisan related options. But when I pass any options / flags, seems like it is propagating those to the phpunit.

@tbhaxor I am a bit ignorant about commands on Linux, but I think the artisan command you are calling is doing that, again, what is artisan doing? can you share the code? What happens if you manually run php artisan test --drop-databases?
